# Why does R Debugger fail to verify all breakpoints (Vscode)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am using R Debugger in Vscode to develop an RShiny app while using SSH to connect to the remote.

My launch.json file looks like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "R-Debugger",
            "name": "Launch R-Workspace",
            "request": "launch",
            "debugMode": "workspace",
            "workingDirectory": "", // If I put my actual path here, it changes nothing
            "allowGlobalDebugging":true
        }
    ]
}
```

For the purposes of this topic, I have these folders/files:

```
src/www/uis 
src/server.R
```

I set breakpoints in files within src/www/uis as well as within src/server.R.
When I use Launch R-Workspace, the breakpoints at src/www/uis will trigger but within src/server.r they turn into "unverified breakpoints".

**What I've tried:**
Reading through similar questions and findings answers that did not seem relevant. Reading through the [documentation](https://manuelhentschel.github.io/vscDebugger/articles/configuration.html) where I did not see anything useful to me.

Any insight?
Thanks

Comment: Facing a similar issue with "unverified breakpoints" (though working locally)